# Why does my calendar not viewed in index page: ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

Hi I tried to implement calendar in my rails test project. so I used 'fullCalendar' gem in project. As I am new to rails, I have followed the below link to see how to use calendar. Now my problem is am unable to get calendar in my rails app. Dont knw what mistake i have done. if anyone knows, pls let me know. i have added the fullCalendar js in application.js and application.css.css also. am completely new to jquery also. then i didnt finish to follow the link. got struggle in the mid. Thanks in advance

**Link**

http://blog.crowdint.com/2014/02/18/fancy-calendars-for-your-web-application-with-fullcalendar.html

**This is my index page**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Events</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Start time</th>
      <th>End time</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
        <td><%= event.description %></td>
        <td><%= event.start_time %></td>
        <td><%= event.end_time %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Event', new_event_path %>
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
</script>
```

**This is my application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require fullcalendar
//= require_tree .
```

**This is application.css.css**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require fullcalendar
 */
```

**Edit**

I have found solution with the help of Mr.Tien. Thanks for the help. Actually the problem is gem file. The gem might be broken. Thats why calnedar didnt come. Now I found another solution. I have posted my application.html.erb in Layouts. This might be useful for someone.

**Answer**

```
  <head>
      <title>CalendarApp</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
       <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/fullcalendar.js' %>
         <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js' %>
      <%= csrf

_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

See the url of fullCalendar and moment. copy the link and paste it in application.html.erb as i mentioned. Problem solved

Comment: all look good. Can you post your js and css code, how you added `callender` js and css file

Comment: Check if you have jQuery loaded. An easy way to do it is to start your application and open the dev console in the browser and type `$.fn.jquery`. That will return your jQuery version. If it does, try typing in `$('#calendar').fullCalendar();` and see what happens.

Comment: @Thomas i have typed 'localhost/events.json' in my browser. it returned all values

Comment: Is your problem that the calendar is not showing or is it that it is not populated with your events?

Comment: My calendar is not showing in my index.html. refer that above link. then you can understand my pblm

Comment: @Thomas i have pasted those line in dev console..it showed me undefined error

Comment: Then your jQuery is not loading. You have to debug that issue first before you move on with anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap your function

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar()
```

in jquery ready function

```
$(function() { $('#calendar').fullCalendar(); })
```

About ready function you can read there http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: still i didnt get calendar

Comment: can you provide in browser dev console output. are there any error?

Comment: dont understand what do u mean?

Comment: @AnitaShalu, what browser are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73406/discussion-between-tien-nguyen-and-anita-shalu).

Comment: Hey @Tien i need ur help..can you come to chat??

Answer (score 0):

Where did you place the `fullcalendar.css` and `.js`? Also there is another fullcalendar gem you can use - I would suggest you add `gem 'fullcalendar_engine'`to your Gemfile, run `bundle install` and `bundle exec rails g fullcalendar_engine:install`. Also make sure to modify your `application.js`:

```
//= require fullcalendar_engine/application
```

and your `application.css`:

```
*= require fullcalendar_engine/application
```

Thats what I would do. You'll find the documentation on https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine

Comment: do i need to write any code for fullCalendar.js and fullCalendar.css??

Comment: Apart from the includes, no. In your view you call fullCalender the way you did before.

Comment: I have called now what @Thomas suggested. is that okay? or do i need to change it as before i used